# Locking Keyboard Onto Raylib Window

Tags: c++, keyboard, raylib

I wanna lock keyboard only onto Window I Created using RayLib, this would be helpful If I created If checks for example Windows key, and the window key does something but doesn't tab out

for example:

```cpp
int key = GetKeyPressed(); // Raylibs Get Key Pressed Function

if (key == 343) { // 343 is Corresponding to windows key
    printf("Hello, World!"); // Printf from standard stdio.h library
}
```

But it wouldn't tab out of the game, it would just print hello world and stay focused on the window